# How to secure JWT authentication Angular + Asp core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created a Angular 5+Asp.Core application and added JWT authentication on existing user database

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
.............
 var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<UserSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
}
```

login controller:

```
    public class LoginController : Controller
        {
            private readonly Entities db;
            private readonly UserSettings appSettings;

            public LoginController(Entities _db, IOptionsSnapshot<UserSettings> _appSettings)
            {
                db = _db;
                appSettings = _appSettings.Value;

            }

            [Route("/api/login")]
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginData logindata)
            {
                var user = db.HT_USERS
                  .SingleOrDefault(u => u.USERNAME == logindata.Username && 
DecryptString128Bit(u.PASSW, "passwkey") == logindata.Password);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {

                    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
                    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                    {
                        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                        {
                          new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier , user.ID.ToString())
                        }),
                        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                        new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                    };


                    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                    var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        username = user.NAME,
                        token = tokenString
                    });

                }
            }
        }
```

From Angular I get token from Login controller and store it to localStorage

inside Angular I get user login status like this:

```
isLoggedIn() {
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.tokenName)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

All seems to work but I don't know what happens if a user log in from 2 devices,on both will have a valid token stored but if it will change the account 
password,on current device token will be updated,what about second device,old token will still works until it expires,
how do I generate a more secure token based some how on user password?

What about above code,it is enough secured to use it in production?
thanks

Comment: That's how JWT tokens work, once issued its valid until it expires. You could put an unique id (or calculate the hash) and store that in memory and on revocation remove it.  Bu the moment you go distributed you have to check it in some remote location (redis cache, database etc.) which partly kills the advantages of having an JWT token in the first time: Not having to do remote checks, just validate the signature and trust it (JWT is a self-contained token secured by a cryptographical means - the signature to prevent tampering; any tampering invalidates the signature so you can trust it)

Comment: If you don't want that you should fall back to other means of security, such as the regular cookie based authentication ASP.NET Identity offers or opaque tokens, which will use the authorization servers introspection endpoint to receive the claims and use the token validation endpoint to validate it

Comment: Hi.thanks for your answer.I'm not so experimented with all stuff so I'll stay with JWT.What about putting a new claim based on user password.If I change the password/new claim,old toke will remain valid?

Comment: It will always remain valid, when the signature is valid and the expiration date did not expire. Everything else requires that you do checks in your code (like making a request to the database to validate it). But this is exactly one thing with JWT was to eliminate, so you **do not require** database queries on each request and will have better and more scalable performance in distributed systems. So adding this checks, will hurt the performance. Like I said, it can be improved by using caches and checking if a specific key is inside the cache (and remove it when user pass changes)

Comment: Its an additional complexity to the system, to manage and invalidate such caches, which you need to consider if thats worth for your use case. Usually the access tokens are fairly short-lived (5 minutes or less), so in case of a compromised access token it will just be usable for a very short amount of time. compromised refresh token usually mean you got an cross-site scripting (xss) vulnerability somewhere so changing password won't necessary fix it neither